# Why jquery addClass does not work on all selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code that is supposed to change my bootstrap nav from `navbar-static-top` to `navbar-fixed-top` but also, I want it to change `<body>` tag by adding or removing class `.fixed-body` . This css class is responsible for changing padding-top style to allow the content to appear. Problem is, the navbar position changes but the body tag does not add or remove the class. Also, the list tag `<li id="home">` remains unaffected. I can see the change on the navbar by inspecting element on my google chrome browser. So, i know that part of the code works. I don't get why the rest does not....

```
            var nav = $('nav');
            var body = $('body');
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > nav.offset().top) {
                    nav.removeClass("navbar-static-top");
                    nav.addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                    body.addClass('fixed-body');
                    $('li#home').removeClass('in');
                }
                else {
                    nav.removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                    nav.addClass("navbar-static-top");                  
                    body.removeClass('fixed-body');
                    $('li#home').addClass('in');
                }
            });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if the script runs from the head, there is no body, so _body_ is memorized empty. use $("body") inside the scroll() handler, or use ready() to make sure that the body is populated.

Comment: The script is at the bottom, right before the </body> tag. I tried both ways with $("body") first then with var body = $("body"). Thanks for the syntax error code notice in my question, not in original code though. Am I missing something here maybe?

Comment: perhaps changing the navbar display scrolls the document a tiny bit, re-firing your handler; use a console.log() or two to findout. or try doing the nav command last, after setting the other classes...